# Can Firefox be "automated"?

Tags: windows, powershell, firefox, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PHP file on the server that creates a backup and then returns it as a zip file. There is no HTML returned, just the ZIP file.

My question is:

How can I call Firefox, pass the URL, and tell it where to save the file, and then have that instance of Firefox close? I plan on using Windows Task Scheduler to call this page once per day. The zip file produced has a unique name.

I've seen the option to pass the url, and that works just fine. I also saw the option to open it in a new window. So far I've tried the code below. It opens the file, and the save file dialog. I want this to happen silently.

If there's a better way to accomplish this using another tool rather than Firefox, that would be very helpful.

```
firefox -new-window https://example.com/bk/makebackup.php?u=username&p=pw&site=site_to_backup
```

Comment: Try the built-in cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` to download the file.

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks, it took a bit of research, but I've almost got it working.